# Пропала панель пользователей Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Я новичок в django и это мой первый проект.Создаю сайт на django с возможностью регистрации пользователей. Но когда решил просмотреть список пользователей, в админ части уже не было панели "Пользователи". Как так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

Мой forms:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from .models import *


class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Логин', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form- 
    input'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Пароль', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 
    'form-input'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Повтор пароля', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs= 
    {'class': 'form-input'}))

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2')
    widgets = {
        'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-input"}),
        'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "form-input"}),
        'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "form-input"}),
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы изменили модель юзеров по умолчанию в файле настройках, поэтому они они пропали в админке, чтобы зарегистрировать свою модель юзеров, добавьте в admin.py

```
@admin.register(models.User)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password', 'password1')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('name', 'email', 'avatar')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {
            'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser'),
        }),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'name', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('username', 'name', 'email')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets