# Проблема с отображением модели в админке

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-model

После того, как я переопределил модель пользователя (`AbstractUser`), в админке перестали отображаться модели (см. 1 скрин).

```py
# models.py
class User(AbstractUser):
    wallet = models.IntegerField('Баланс', default=0)


class App(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField('Описание', blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='upload/')
    time_create = models.DateTimeField('Время создания', auto_now_add=True)
    time_update = models.DateTimeField('Время обновления', auto_now=True)
    time_start = models.DateTimeField('Время запуска', auto_now=True)
    is_run = models.BooleanField('Запущен', default=True)
```

```py
# settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.User'
```

После проведения миграций и созданию суперюзера, это привело к такому виду админки:

[image: Результат после совершенных манипуляций]

Следуя решению из [этой темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1316944/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-django-admin), я добавил в admin.py следующий код:

```py
# admin.py
@admin.register(models.User)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {"fields": ("username", "password")}),
        (_("Personal info"), {"fields": ("first_name", "last_name", "email", "wallet",)}),
        (
            _("Permissions"),
            {
                "fields": (
                    "is_active",
                    "is_staff",
                    "is_superuser",
                    "groups",
                    "user_permissions",
                ),
            },
        ),
        (_("Important dates"), {"fields": ("last_login", "date_joined")}),
    )

    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    change_password_form = AdminPasswordChangeForm
    list_display = ("username", "email", "first_name", "last_name", "is_staff")
    list_filter = ("is_staff", "is_superuser", "is_active", "groups")
    search_fields = ("username", "first_name", "last_name", "email")
    ordering = ("username",)
    filter_horizontal = (
        "groups",
        "user_permissions",
    )
```

Что привело к добавлению в админку модели пользователей:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако модель `App` все еще не видна. Есть ли быстрый способ отобразить все существующие модели в админке после переопределения `AbstractUser` или теперь надо каждую модель регистрировать вручную?

Comment: «надо каждую модель регистрировать вручную» — да, всегда так было

Comment: Блин, чувствую теперь себя сейчас глупо. Так давно не работал с админкой, что забыл о том, что надо регистрировать в ней модели. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для отображения модели в админке, необходимо в файле `admin.py` добавить строку
`admin.site.register(<название вашей модели>)`
в моем случае это:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import App, User


admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(App)
```